# Running Pure 32-Bit ELF ARM Binary on BlueStacks

Tags: android, mobile, bluestacks

I'm trying to run a Pure 32-Bit ELF ARM Binary on a rooted bluestacksv4 emulated device. I'm getting following error

./mybin: not executable: 32-bit ELF file

I reazlize I'm running an ARM bin on x86, however I read [here](http://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/Android_emulators) Bluestacks by default have ARM emulation .

I'm on an Windows 10 ( with Intel proc ) system, how can I run that binary using an emulated Android device.

Answer (score 1):

If the file itself was not marked as executable in the filesystem you can change that by `chmod a+x ./mybin`.

Comment: Same issue here, the file is marked as executable but still the error appears "not executable: 32-bit ELF file"